# Call a C Program within Another and Get the Child's Output in macOS

Tags: c, parent-child

I have two C programs and am trying to call some child program "child.c" inside of some parent program "parent.c", and capturing the output to stdout from child.c. How would I go about doing this?

I am using macOS.

Here's an example of what parent.c and child.c might look like

*parent.c*

```
while (1)
{
    // call the child program
    // capture the output from the child
    if (child_output == some_condition)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

*child.c*

```
printf("Hello world!")
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`popen()`](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/popen.3.html) and create a stream object of type `FILE *` which you can use with `fread()`/`fgets()` to get the output from the child program. Reading the manual page should be enough to get you started.

But here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *pipe;
    char line[256];
    pipe = popen("ls", "r");
    if (pipe != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, pipe) != NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        }
        pclose(pipe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, read the manual to get an idea of how this actually works.